# C++ Meshes getting animated when they are not suppose too

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-c++, directx

I have two meshes.  One of them is animated and the other one is not animated.  When i render them the inanimate mesh gets animated the same way the animated mesh is animating.
So, let just the animated mesh goes to left than comes back, my inanimate mesh does the same thing!
This is my code class for the inanimate meshes.
main class

```
class StaticMesh
{
public:
    StaticMesh(LPDIRECT3DDEVICE9* device);
    ~StaticMesh(void);
    void Render(void);
    void Load(LPCWSTR fileName);
    void CleanUp(void);
private:
    LPDIRECT3DDEVICE9* d3ddev;                      // the pointer to the device class
    LPD3DXMESH mesh;    // define the mesh pointer
    D3DMATERIAL9* material;    // define the material object
    DWORD numMaterials;    // stores the number of materials in the mesh
    LPDIRECT3DTEXTURE9* texture;    // a pointer to a texture
    LPD3DXBUFFER bufMeshMaterial;
};

#include "StdAfx.h"
#include "StaticMesh.h"


StaticMesh::StaticMesh(LPDIRECT3DDEVICE9* device)
{
    d3ddev=device;
}


StaticMesh::~StaticMesh(void)
{
}

void StaticMesh::Render(void)
{
    LPDIRECT3DDEVICE9 device=*d3ddev;
    for(DWORD i = 0; i < numMaterials; i++)    // loop through each subset
    {
        device->SetMaterial(&material[i]);    // set the material for the subset
        device->SetTexture(0, texture[i]);    // ...then set the texture

        mesh->DrawSubset(i);    // draw the subset
    }
}

void StaticMesh::Load(LPCWSTR fileName)
{
    LPDIRECT3DDEVICE9 device=*d3ddev;

    D3DXLoadMeshFromX(fileName,    // load this file
                      D3DXMESH_SYSTEMMEM,    // load the mesh into system memory
                      device,    // the Direct3D Device
                      NULL,    // we aren't using adjacency
                      &bufMeshMaterial,    // put the materials here
                      NULL,    // we aren't using effect instances
                      &numMaterials,    // the number of materials in this model
                      &mesh);    // put the mesh here

    // retrieve the pointer to the buffer containing the material information
    D3DXMATERIAL* tempMaterials = (D3DXMATERIAL*)bufMeshMaterial->GetBufferPointer();

    // create a new material buffer and texture for each material in the mesh
    material = new D3DMATERIAL9[numMaterials];
    texture = new LPDIRECT3DTEXTURE9[numMaterials];

    for(DWORD i = 0; i < numMaterials; i++)    // for each material...
    {
         // Copy the material 
         material[i] = tempMaterials[i].MatD3D; 

         // Set the ambient color for the material (D3DX does not do this) 
         material[i].Ambient = material[i].Diffuse; 

         // Create the texture if it exists - it may not 
         texture[i] = NULL; 
         if (tempMaterials[i].pTextureFilename) 
         {
             D3DXCreateTextureFromFileA(device, tempMaterials[i].pTextureFilename,&texture[i]);  
         }
     }
}

void StaticMesh::CleanUp(void)
{
    mesh->Release();
}
```

Comment: I have a feeling your problem exists outside of the class you've supplied. Can you include a sample of what operations you're performing on your StaticMesh objects?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The anination comes from a transformation matrix.
You either pass that directly to the device (if using fixed function) or to a shader/effect.
All meshes you draw after the matrix has been set will undergo the same transform.
So, if you want to have one mesh stay inanimate you have to change the transform before drawing the mesh.

Pseudo-code:

```
SetTransform( world* view * projection );
DrawMesh();
SetTransform( identity * view * projection );
DrawMesh();
```